# HBASE filter by multiple values

Tags: java, hbase

I am having problems using filters to search data in hbase.

First I am reading some data from one table and storing in a vector or arrayList:

```
    for (Result r : rs) {
        for (KeyValue kv : r.raw()) {
            if (new String(kv.getFamily()).equals("mpnum")) {
                temp = new String(kv.getValue());
                x.addElement(temp);

            }
        }
    }
```

Then, I want to search a different table based on the values of this vector. I used filters to do this: (I tried `BinaryPrefixComparator` and `BinaryComparator` as well)

```
  FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);    


    for (int c = 0; c < x.size(); c++) {
       System.out.println(x.get(c).toString());          
       filterList.addFilter(new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("mpnum"), null, CompareOp.EQUAL, new SubstringComparator( x.get(c).toString()  )));

    }
```

I should get 3 results back, however I only get one result back, the first entry in the database.
What doesn't make sense is that when I hardcode the value that I am looking for into my code, I will get all 3 results back.

I thought there might be some issue with converting the bytes to String and then back to bytes, but that would not explain how it was able to bring back the first result. For some reason, it is stopping at the first match and doesn't continue to find the other 2 rows that contain matching data. If I hardcode it i get the results:

```
x.addElement("abc123");
filterList.addFilter(new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("mpnum"), null, CompareOp.EQUAL, new SubstringComparator( x.get(0).toString()  )));
```

Does anyone know what the problem is or what I need to do to resolve my issue? Your help is much appreciated.

Thank You

edit: Here is the contents of the tables:

**TABLE1:**
ROW                                                 COLUMN+CELL
 0                                                  column=gpnum:, timestamp=1481300288449, value=def123
 0                                                  column=mpnum:, timestamp=1481300273355, value=**abc123**
 0                                                  column=price:, timestamp=1481300255337, value=85.0
 1                                                  column=gpnum:, timestamp=1481301599999, value=def2244
 1                                                  column=mpnum:, timestamp=1481301582336, value=**011511607**
 1                                                  column=price:, timestamp=1481301673886, value=0.76

**TABLE2**

ROW                                                 COLUMN+CELL
 0                                                  column=brand:, timestamp=1481300227283, value=x
 0                                                  column=mpnum:, timestamp=1481300212289, value=**abc123**
 0                                                  column=price:, timestamp=1481300110950, value=50.0
 1                                                  column=mpnum:, timestamp=1481301806687, value=**011511607**
 1                                                  column=price:, timestamp=1481301777345, value=1.81
 13                                                 column=webtype:, timestamp=1483507543878, value=US
 3                                                  column=avail:, timestamp=1481306538360, value=avail
 3                                                  column=brand:, timestamp=1481306538360, value=brand
 3                                                  column=descr:, timestamp=1481306538360, value=description
 3                                                  column=dist:, timestamp=1481306538360, value=distributor
 3                                                  column=mpnum:, timestamp=1481306538360, value=pnum
 3                                                  column=price:, timestamp=1481306538360, value=price
 3                                                  column=url:, timestamp=1481306538360, value=url
 3                                                  column=webtype:, timestamp=1481306538360, value=webtype
 4                                                  column=avail:, timestamp=1481306538374, value=4
 4                                                  column=brand:, timestamp=1481306538374, value=x
 4                                                  column=descr:, timestamp=1481306538374, value=description
 4                                                  column=dist:, timestamp=1481306538374, value=x
 4                                                  column=mpnum:, timestamp=1482117383212, value=**011511607**
 4                                                  column=price:, timestamp=1481306538374, value=34.51
 4                                                  column=url:, timestamp=1481306538374, value=x
 4                                                  column=webtype:, timestamp=1481306538374, value=US
 5                                                  column=avail:, timestamp=1481306538378, value=
 5                                                  column=brand:, timestamp=1481306538378, value=name
 5                                                  column=descr:, timestamp=1481306538378, value=x
 5                                                  column=dist:, timestamp=1481306538378, value=x
 5                                                  column=mpnum:, timestamp=1482117392043, value=**011511607**
 5                                                  column=price:, timestamp=1481306538378, value=321.412
 5                                                  column=url:, timestamp=1481306538378, value=x.com

**THIRD TABLE (to store result matches)**

0                                                  column=brand:, timestamp=1481301813849, value=name
 0                                                  column=cprice:, timestamp=1481301813849, value=1.81
 0                                                  column=gpnum:, timestamp=1481301813849, value=def2244
 0                                                  column=gprice:, timestamp=1481301813849, value=0.76
 0                                                  column=mpnum:, timestamp=1481301813849, value=011511607

**should be three matches those that are in bold above but only brings back one match

**If anyone is willing to help for a fee, send me an email at tt224416@gmail.com**

Comment: have you checked the value of `temp`?  Maybe an encoding issue?

Comment: @MartinSerrano Yes, I have checked the values of temp and the data is correct

Comment: can you share some more detail?Like table data for corresponding rows as it should give desired rows if you are checking for substring.And maybe,your complete code snippet of filter application and scan/get?

Comment: Thank You for your help. I appreciate it. I have added more info. Send me an email at  tt224416@gmail.com and I will send you my code.